# Joomla component: controller not returning json

Tags: joomla, components

Why is my controller not returning my data in JSON format? Note that I am developing my component on Joomla 3.1.1.

**/hmi.php**

```
//Requries the joomla's base controller
    jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');


    //Create the controller
    $controller = JControllerLegacy::getInstance('HMI');

    //Perform the Request task
    $controller ->execute(JRequest::setVar('view', 'hmimain'));

    //Redirects if set by the controller
    $controller->redirect();
```

**/controller.php**

```
class HMIController extends JControllerLegacy
{

function __construct()
{
    //Registering Views
    $this->registerTask('hmimain', 'hmiMain');
    parent::__construct();
}


function hmiMain()
{
    $view =& $this->getView('hmimain','html');
    $view->setModel($this->getModel('hmimain'), true);

    $view->display();
}



public function saveHMI()
{
    echo 'Testing';
    $this->display();
}

}//End of class HMIController
```

**/controllers/properties.json.php**

```
 class HMIControllerProperties extends JController
  {

        function __construct()
        {
            $this->registerTask(' taskm', 'taskM');
            parent::__construct();
        }

      function taskM()
      {

          $document =& JFactory::getDocument();

          // Set the MIME type for JSON output.
          $document->setMimeEncoding('application/json');

          // Change the suggested filename.
          JResponse::setHeader('Content-Disposition','attachment;filename="json.json"');


          echo json_encode('Hello World');
          // Exit the application.
          Jexit();
      }
  }
```

JQuery function calling the joomla task

```
var request = $.ajax({
        dataType:"json",
        url:"index.php?option=com_hmi&task=properties.taskm&format=json",
        type:"POST",
        data:{propPage: "ABC"},
        beforeSend: function (){
            $("#loading_Bar").css("display","block");
        }
    });// dot ajax
```

When I use the above ajax settings the request fails. However if I change the datatype property to text, and remove the `format=json` from the url, I get html instead of json.

Can some one point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further investigation to my problem i concluded that the componenet was not triggering the desired task becuse of the following code in my **/hmi.php**

> $controller ->execute(JRequest::setVar('view', 'hmimain'));

So I modified my **/hmi.php** as follows

```
        //Requries the joomla's base controller
    jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');

    // Create the controller
    $controller   = JControllerLegacy::getInstance('HMI');

    $selectedTask = JRequest::getVar( 'task');

    if ($selectedTask == null)
    {
        //This will allow you to access the main view using index?option=com_hmi
        //and load the "default" view
        $controller->execute( JRequest::setVar( 'view', 'hmimain' ) );
    }
    else
    {
        //Will execute the assigned task
        $controller->execute( JRequest::getVar( 'task' ) );
    }


    // Redirect if set by the controller
    $controller->redirect();
```

then created the **/controllers/properties.json.php** file with the following code

```
        class HMIControllerProperties extends JControllerLegacy
    {

        function myMethod()
        {
            $model = $this->getModel('hmimain');        
            $dataToolboxItems =& $model->getToolboxItems();

            echo json_encode($dataToolboxItems);

            //JExit();
        }




    }//End of class HMIController
```

then i'm calling the task from jquery as follows:

```
    var request = $.ajax({
        dataType:"json",
        //task=properties.mymethod will access the subcontroller within the controllers folder
        //format=json will by access the json version of the subcontroller
        url:"index.php?option=com_hmi&task=properties.mymethod&format=json",
        type:"POST",
        data:{propPage: "ABC"},
        beforeSend: function (){
            $("#loading_Bar").css("display","block");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax request try changing to this format:

```
dataType:'json',
url: 'index.php',
data: {option: 'com_hmi', task: 'properties.task', format: 'jason', propPage: 'ABC' },
type:'POST',
```

.....

Another thing is in the controller file add the Legacy:
HMIControllerProperties extends JControllerLegacy

And I don't think you need this lines, for me it works without them

```
$document->setMimeEncoding('application/json');
JResponse::setHeader('Content-Disposition','attachment;filename="json.json"');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply....however there was no luck with your solution :/....With further investigation i noticed that the componenet wasn't triggering the task within the controller.php. The code in my /hmi.php was not correct